# how to know which iOS developer program I am using?

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution

Actually I have a client ios developer program that I am using to upload app on apple store also I can distribute adhoc with enterprise option.

I am confuse about I am using $99 or @299 iOS developer program. Some say you can't upload app on apple store if you are using Enterprise ios developer Program.

Could anyone provide me clue how to know which ios developer program I am using.

If it is Enterprise then I would like to distribute in house app without registering UDID of devices and how many distribution I can make in In-House and what will be the procedure?

Comment: Could anyone tell me why this question closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Link  [Get everything you need to develop and distribute apps for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/). : https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/

The main Diffrence is in  ios Standard program($99) you can Distribute the App to All Public. But in case of Enterprise ($299) you can Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS apps to your employees. You can also securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to employees.
Source : https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

1. To Know About Which programme you are having Click on The Link : https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary and Login with your id and password. Then in Account Summary (in the tab Your ccount) you can see Your Account Summary as well as Expiration date. Ex:  **iOS Developer Program , Expiration Date: Sep xx, xxxx**
2. Check this Link: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1434-how-to-prepare-an-iphone-app-for-ad-hoc-distribution/    to know about How to Prepare an iPhone App for Ad Hoc Distribution

Comment: But in this link https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary
Does not state that it is Standard Or Enterprise Account ?
And the apple docs are not enough to distribute in house app Without using UDID ?

Comment: Check In your Account Summary its iOS developer Program or Enterprise program ?

Comment: I did carefully after that I posted ques. on SO.

Comment: ok but my question do you have any clue to figure out which ios developer program I am using after login to developer program? and how to distribute in-house app without using UDID? I can distribute using UDID.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time. I have got solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ad-hoc(In House) you can distribute application to only 100 devices per year with Enterprise profile.
You can upload you app on app store using Enterprise profile also.

Comment: But using $99 you can also distribute app on 100 devices then what will be benefit to spend $299 for enterprise ios program. And what will be the difference between ios Standard program($99) and iOS Enterprise ($299)?. After login to ios program is there any way to figure out which program I am using ?

Comment: FYK you can't distribute to apple store using iOS Enterprise Distribution($299). Because there is not option for app store.